# What to do with stickers?

Tags: hatch

I keep finding stickers despite having lots already.

What is their purpose? What do I do with the stickers?

Answer (score 1):

Stickers can be stored in a notebook and shared with others via social networks or messaging. Stickers are consumables and if you share a sticker via twitter or message, it is removed from your sticker book.